# Fetching Values from Amazon rds to react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-hooks, amazon-rds

I have all the details of amazon RDS like Endpoint, username, password, database_name. I want to connect the RDS into my React app and need to do some operations on those values.

Any idea of how to fetch values from aws RDS for my react app ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do this is to create a backend for your app that your frontend communicates with through an API.

For a serverless backend, you can for example use an API Gateway REST API that is connected to an AWS Lambda function. The Lambda function will then query the RDS database and return the results of the queries through the API. You can find an explanation for how to query RDS from Lambda here: [Configuring a Lambda function to access Amazon RDS in an Amazon VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-rds-tutorial.html)

From your React application, you can then send queries to the API with `axios`, for example. [Here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/fetch-api-data-with-axios-and-display-it-in-a-react-app-with-hooks-3f9c8fa89e7b) is a guide for how to do that.